# Impact of IV on coefficients for exogenous regressors

Tags: regression, linear-regression, instruments

I am sorry if my question sounds a bit naive, but I am new to IV and have a problem. One of the variables in my regression is endogenous, and I use 2SLS to remove bias. In stage 2 I focused on the coefficient for this particular variable, but also noticed that the coefficients and error terms for some other variables have also changed. Are these estimates for these (exogenous) variables more reliable than those from the OLS?

Comment: From my understanding, when your instrument is as good as random you don't need any more controls to remove the bias. Still, often the same set of variables is used like in OLS. Perhaps the instrument is conditionally exogenous. I think this is a question for Cross Validated.

Comment: Thank you! Could this result indicate the presence of another endogenous variable?